# Powershell parsing of a C# file to get values of constants

Tags: powershell

I need to parse some `C#` files to get the values of some constant variables. I know I can do something like

`$input = Get-Content C:\somefile.cs ...`

then loop over each line and do some text matching.

...but was wondering whether I can utilize some sort of a `C#` DOM object to get the values of constants?

Comment: PowerShell can compile C# into an assembly that gets loaded in the current  AppDomain. To do this use `Add-Type`. Perhaps you can just use the existing file and have the constants get loaded directly this way?

Comment: Pattern matching would probably be much simpler and faster. You don't need to match blocks of code, as const statements are single line. If you want more details, please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: Need to get  XYZ from this class. <br>using System;
using System.Text;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    static class MyClass
    {
        private const string abc = "XYZ";
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

You can load the type dynamically from the powershell command line, and then evaluate the constant.

**Example:**

*C:\somefile.cs contents:*

```
public static class Foo
{
    public const string SOME_CONSTANT = "StackOverflow";
}
```

*Powershell command line:*

```
Add-Type -Path C:\somefile.cs
$constantValue = [Foo]::SOME_CONSTANT
```